# Windows 7, accelerometer and other sensors

Tags: windows, accelerometer, sensors

I have got a tabletPC that has acclerometer inside, Windows 7 detects how device is oriented. Is there any possibility to use accelrometer data in my application and where to start?

Comment: I searched for some information but there is a lot about Windows Phone accelerometer programming.

Comment: I didn't want to ask about Phone 7

Comment: What is your application written in?

Comment: In C++ but C# examples are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used it, but you might look at the [Windows Sensor and Location Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463473.aspx) APIs.